# React Logout User and Redirect to Login Page when Refresh Token Expires

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

I am having this challenge in React JS. I have designed my system to use Token Refresh and Token Rotation, so when the token expires, the backend deletes the cookie automatically, which should also happen in the frontend by deleting the localStorage variable that stores the token and redirecting user to the login page. I am using Axios interceptors to automatically check on response errors if it is error 403 and hit on the `/refresh` endpoint with the refresh token. The challenge is, when this refresh fails, meaning the token has expired, I am unable to redirect the user automatically to the login page. That is, the localStorage token is not deleted which should happen when the refresh token fails. It takes 2 or 3-page refreshes for the token to be deleted and the user to be finally redirected to the login page. During these attempts, no data is loaded, which is expected since the backend has already logged out the user by deleting the cookie from the backend, hence it can be frustrating to the users. This is my code for further understanding.

axiosPrivate.js

```
import { setIsAuthenticated } from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import instance from "./axiosConfig";

import { memoizedRefreshToken } from "./axiosRefreshToken";

instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        const authenticatedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"));
    
        if (authenticatedUser?.accessToken) {
            config.headers = {
                ...config.headers,
                authorization: `Bearer ${authenticatedUser?.accessToken}`,
            };
        }
    
        return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    async (error) => {
        const config = error?.config;
    
        if (error?.response?.status === 403 && !config?.sent) {
            config.sent = true;
            console.log("Inside If: ", config);
    
            const result = await memoizedRefreshToken();
    
            if (result?.accessToken) {
                console.log("Access Token Returned: ", result)
                config.headers = {
                    ...config.headers,
                    authorization: `Bearer ${result?.accessToken}`,
                };
            } else {
                console.log("No Access Token ")
                store.dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(false));
            }
    
            return instance(config);
        }
        console.log("Outside If: ", config);
        store.dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(false));
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export const axiosPrivate = instance;
```

axiosRefreshToken.js

```
import { store } from '../features/store';
import { setIsAuthenticated } from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import instance from "./axiosConfig";

const refreshTokenFn = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await instance.get("/auth/refresh");

        const authenticatedUser = response.data;

        if (!authenticatedUser?.accessToken) {
            localStorage.removeItem("authenticatedUser");
            store.dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(false));
        }

        localStorage.setItem("authenticatedUser", JSON.stringify(authenticatedUser));
        store.dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(true));

        return authenticatedUser;
    } catch (error) {
        localStorage.removeItem("authenticatedUser");
        store.dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(false));
    }
};

const maxAge = 10000;

export const memoizedRefreshToken = mem(refreshTokenFn, {
    maxAge,
});
```

I have a feeling that the problem is in the `axiosRefreshToken.js` but I am unable to trace down what I am doing wrong. Kindly advise.

###### UPDATE

I am thinking that the issue is in the `axiosRefreshToken.js` where when there is no response, nothing is returned and the error catching after that does not as well work as expected. My expectation is that when there is no response, error catching under that kicks in and deletes the localStorage token immediately. But by debugging, it will take like 3 page refreshes to get that error catching working.

Answer (score 0):

After so much digging and testing, I think the issue with the code was using memoization of the function in the `axiosRefreshToken.js` file. I removed the mem function and it automatically catches the error and fires the dispatch function instantly when the token is not refreshed. However, if there is a better way of handling this, I would gladly welcome it.